# Displaying an Image in java

Tags: java, swing, background, window

I am having problems displaying an image on a frame.  When the picture is displayed the top left corner doesn't go to the (0,0) specified, also the background of the window takes on visual components of whatever was behind the window when I first ran it.  Does anybody know what's wrong?  Thanks in advance-

```
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{
//the pictures
Image testImage = null;
Image backPic  = null;


//constructor
Window(){
    super("window");
    this.startWindow();
}

public void startWindow(){
    Image customIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("iconImage.gif");
    testImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tester.gif");
    backPic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("black.png");
    setSize(700,600);
    setIconImage(customIcon);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}


public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(testImage,0,0,null);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you call `new Window()` from the EDT (`SwingUtilities.invokeLater...`)?

Comment: Also, you might need to call `super.paint(g)` to paint the rest of the frame.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your testImage is not yet fully loaded when `paint()` is called. To fix this, you can invoke this instead:

```
g.drawImage(testImage,0,0,this);
```

But my preferred approach would be to use a JLabel and let it handle the image drawing. I also strongly recommend to not override `JFrame.paint()` (and if you do, at least call `super.paint(g)`). If you really want to draw an image yourself, extend `JComponent` and override `paintComponent()`

Answer (score 2):

So my advice to you use `JLabels` for example to show `Images`, it's the simpliest way you can sure use. I created similar basic project that demonstate this way.

```
/**
 * @author Sajmon
 */

package com.sajmon.window;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private JLabel pictureLabel;
    private Container controls;

    public Window() {
        super("window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.startWindow();
    }

    private void startWindow() {
        controls = new Container();
        controls = getContentPane();
        controls.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pictureLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("picture.png"));
        controls.add(pictureLabel);
    }
}
```

And Main method for run application.

```
/**
 *
 * @author Sajmon
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Window w = new Window();
                w.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

**Note:** If you working with Swing, you should starting your application with Runnable interface. This way is generally recommended.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Small thing, but you should create a left align flow layout with no gaps, so that the image appears in 0,0: `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0)`

Comment: so its only basic example, developer can select layout that he need.